# What percentage of a population will flip n heads in a row?

Tags: statistics

If a population flips a coin, say, 10 times, what percentage of them will flip ten consecutive heads? Is it just as simple as $0.5^{10} \approx 0.1\% $ of the population will get this result? Or would be something along the lines of the portion of the normal distribution with area $0.001$?

Comment: What is the distinction you are making between the results?  The first answer $(0.5^{10})$ is exact.

Comment: If 1,000,000 people do this 10 coin flip, are 1,000 people expected to see the ten consecutive heads?

Comment: @WarrenL. Yes, we can expect around 1000 people to get 10 heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *expected* percentage is $0.5^{10}$ ... but obviously the *actual* percentage can be different. In that sense you get a normal distribution of possible outcomes for that percentage ... but the area will still be 1: the sum of probabilities for each of those possible outcomes is 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward application of the binomial probability distribution.  If $Z$ is the number of heads in ten tosses, we have

$$P(Z = k) = {10\choose k}\cdot{1\over 2^{10}}$$

for $0 \le k \le 10$.